# Fan control using buck converter

Tags: buck, fan, esp32

I have a 12 V motorcycle battery hooked up to a buck-boost converter, giving me a constant 12 V supply. This buck-boost converter is then hooked up to a normal buck-converter giving me 7.5 V. I know I could vary the buck-boost to 7.5 V, but because I want to power other 12 V devices later on, I need to add another buck for the 7.5 V fan supply.

Question: When I hook my fan up to the out+ and out- of the buck converter, the fan spins. However, when I use the GND from my ESP32 instead of out-, the fan doesn't spin at all. Why is this?

Comment: The converter may be isolated thus not sharing the same ground.

Comment: 1) Draw a schematic 2) *when I use the GND from my ESP32* Where did that ESP32 suddenly come from? 3) Are ths OUT- and GND of the ESP32 properly connected using good (soldered?) connections and not-too-thin wire? If so then it should not make a difference where the GND of the fan is connected. If the ESP's GND connection is poor then anything can happen as the fan starts drawing current.

Comment: Note you can probably put the buck converter in parallel to the buck boost, since its drop out voltage is probably lower than you'd want to discharge a lead acid battery.  This will save power by avoiding two conversions.  Also note that switching converters usually have max efficiency at rated output.  Good converters will provide an efficiency vs load graph instead of just peak efficiency.

Comment: @Damien How can I validate this?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie 1) I am going to draw a schematic. 2) The ESP32 is just a addition, it is not really necessary for my problem. 3) The grounds of the ESP are good. They work like they should on other components. For some reason, it does make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The current from your 7.5V buck converter flows through your fan and needs to go back to the buck converter to build a closed current loop - you cannot connect just a random ground.
This means, as stated in the comments, if the buck (or the buck/boost) converter is isolated and doesn't share the same ground as your ESP32, the current loop is not closed.

You can verify this with a multimeter and measure the resistance between the two grounds, should be close to 0Ohms.

Comment: Ah alright, I think I understand now. The multimeter also gave 0Ohms indeed. But why isn't the current able to flow to another ground? Because that would also close the loop right? Or does the loop has to be closed through the buck converter because the buck converter needs some sort of feedback? Or does the current simply needs to go back to the current source? Sorry if this is all extremely basic, because it surely sounds like it..

Comment: Yes, the current has to go back to its source because the "system" strives for potential equilibrium.